# ThreadpoolController causing a Flask server (via passenger_wsgi) to fail to load while importing Numpy

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, flask, passenger

I am playing around with a Flask-based webpage.  If it matters, it's hosted on A2 Hosting shared hosting server.  I have a basic working flask page that accepts user input and a file upload via a form.  I also have a simple Python script that simplifies an image to a user-defined number of colors.  I had errors running the image manipulation script because it uses KMeans from sklearn, and thread creation was failing. I solved that problem by forcing it to use a single OpenMP thread as follows:

```
from threadpoolctl import ThreadpoolController, threadpool_limits
controller = ThreadpoolController()

@controller.wrap(limits=1, user_api='openmp')
def simplify_image():
    etc...
```

With that fix in place, I can now successfully run the image simplification utility from the command line on the server that hosts the website.  However, now when I go to restart the Python web app, which imports the image manipulation utility, it fails to load.  Log output is pasted in at the bottom.  To be clear, it would load fine with the utility as an import before I limited that function to a single thread, and now it fails.  Looking at the logs, it gets as far as importing Numpy before it fails to create a bunch of OpenBLAS threads and ends with a keyboard interrupt.  It seems obvious to me that this is some side effect of my fix, but I don't understand why it would be affecting the import of a module when I've restricted the thread limitation only one function, and the script isn't currently running.

So to summarize,

- The Flask portion works as expected
- The image script works fine on its own when limited to 1 OpenMP thread
- I put them together and it fails, evidently because it can't create OpenBLAS threads when importing Numpy

Here is the Flask code...

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import simplify_image_to_approved_colors
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename ='./flask_app.log', level = logging.ERROR)
logging.error("Started flask server.")

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
template_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'templates')
static_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'static')
upload_path = os.path.join(static_path, UPLOAD_FOLDER)
simplified_image_path = os.path.join(upload_path, 'simplified')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_path, static_folder=static_path)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = upload_path

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'SEND', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Handle uploads
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Save original image
        if 'file1' not in request.files:
            return 'there is no file1 in form!'
        file1 = request.files['file1']
        path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file1.filename)
        file1.save(path)
        
        # Run pattern generator
        is_circle = None
        if request.form["is_circle"] == "yes":
            is_circle = True
        else:
            is_circle = False
        image_path = path
        num_colors = int(request.form["max_colors"])
        target_width = int(request.form["width"])
        line_spacing = int(request.form["count"])

        pattern_location = simplify_image_to_approved_colors.simplify_image(template_path, simplified_image_path, image_path, num_colors, target_width=target_width, line_spacing=line_spacing, is_circle=is_circle)
        return f"{pattern_location} \n {request.form}"
        
    # Default homepage
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/configure_pattern', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def configure_pattern(pitch, width, is_circle):
    return render_template("configure_pattern.html", pitch=pitch, width=width, is_circle=is_circle)

@app.route('/results')
def results(pattern_filename):
    return render_template("results.html", link=f"https://www.thestarvingmartian.com/chromacross/patterns/{pattern_filename}")


application = app
```

Though it's probably not necessary, here are the imports and the function that uses Numpy.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from PIL import Image
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor
import dmc_colors_list
import os
import logging
from threadpoolctl import ThreadpoolController, threadpool_limits

logging.basicConfig( 
        filename = 'app.log', 
        level = logging.WARNING, 
        format = '%(levelname)s:%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
        
controller = ThreadpoolController()

@controller.wrap(limits=1, user_api='openmp')
def simplify_image(pattern_path, simplified_image_path, image_path, num_colors, valid_colors=np.array([color[2] for color in dmc_colors_list.dmc_colors]), target_width=None, line_spacing=14, is_circle=False, verbose=False):
    global image_name
    image_name = image_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    target_width = target_width * line_spacing
    
    # Load the image
    if verbose: print("Opening the image...")
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    
    # Scale the image if target_width is specified
    if verbose: print("Preparing to simplify the image...")
    if target_width is not None:
        aspect_ratio = image.width / image.height
        target_height = int(target_width / aspect_ratio)
        image = image.resize((target_width, target_height))

    # Convert the image to a numpy array
    if verbose: print("Converting image to a numpy array and reshaping...")
    image_array = np.array(image)
    
    # Reshape the image array to a 2D array of pixels
    pixels = image_array.reshape(-1, 3)
    
    # Perform k-means clustering
    if verbose: print("Doing k-means magic...")
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_colors, n_init="auto")
    kmeans.fit(pixels)
    
    # Get the cluster labels for each pixel
    labels = kmeans.predict(pixels)
    
    # Get the unique colors (centroids) assigned by k-means
    unique_colors = kmeans.cluster_centers_
    
    # Create a Nearest Neighbors model
    if verbose: print("Doing nearest neighbors stuff to create new pixels...")
    nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
    nn.fit(valid_colors)
    
    # Find the nearest match for each unique color
    if verbose: print("Finding nearest matches...")
    _, indices = nn.kneighbors(unique_colors)
    nearest_colors = valid_colors[indices.flatten()]
    
    # Replace each pixel with the corresponding nearest matching color
    if verbose: print("Replacing pixels with nearest matches...")
    new_pixels = nearest_colors[labels]
    
    # Reshape the new pixel array to match the original image shape
    if verbose: print("Reshaping new pixels...")
    new_image_array = new_pixels.reshape(image_array.shape)
    
    # Create a new PIL image from the simplified pixel array
    if verbose: print("Creating new image with PIL...")
    new_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(new_image_array))
    
    # Save the simplified image as JPEG
    if verbose: print("Saving new image...")
    new_path = os.path.join(simplified_image_path, f"simplified_{image_name}.jpg")
    new_image.save(new_path)
```

Log output

```
App 19383 output: OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 9 of 32: Resource temporarily unavailable
App 19383 output: OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
```

*Next 21 identical errors omitted...*

```
App 19383 output: OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 31 of 32: Resource temporarily unavailable
App 19383 output: OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
App 19383 output: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 19383 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
App 19383 output:     app_module = load_app()
App 19383 output:   File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
App 19383 output:     return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
App 19383 output:   File "/opt/alt/python310/lib64/python3.10/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
App 19383 output:     module = _load(spec)
App 19383 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
App 19383 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
App 19383 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
App 19383 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/chromacross/passenger_wsgi.py", line 3, in <module>
App 19383 output:     import simplify_image_to_approved_colors
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/chromacross/simplify_image_to_approved_colors.py", line 2, in <module>
App 19383 output:     import numpy as np
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/virtualenv/chromacross/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
App 19383 output:     from . import core
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/virtualenv/chromacross/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
App 19383 output:     from . import multiarray
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/virtualenv/chromacross/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
App 19383 output:     from . import overrides
App 19383 output:   File "/home/thestarv/virtualenv/chromacross/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
App 19383 output:     from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
App 19383 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 216, in _lock_unlock_module
App 19383 output: KeyboardInterrupt
```